# ipa.cpp:456 /cannot find .app/Info.plist

Tags: iphone, ios

I was trying to install an ipa file onto my iPhone 6plus. I unpacked the file for looking into its contents and I packed it again and tried to install it through Cydia Impactor but I got this error! Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try re-downloading the ipa?

Comment: .app/Info.plist is missing, repackage the app after assuring this file does exist in .app folder. Folders start with "." is hidden by default,and you might need to use the terminal and command "ls -a" to find this folder.